# Minimal optimization using a cost function

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, numerical-optimization

[image]

The **above image** is data that cannot be saved in a list because there's too much of it. This image is just a small snippet of what my real data looks like. The plot is created by some cost function $y=f(k)$... where $y$ is the vertical axis and $k$ is the horizontal axis. We are **guaranteed** there will be only two points shown in yellow, $0=f(k_n)$ and $0=f(k_m)$. I know both the far left and far right data points. What is the most efficient method to find either $k_n$ or $k_m$ that make $y=0$? The value of $k$ is not a root.

$f(k_n) = \frac{\sqrt{B_n}}{2\sqrt{A_n}} - 1$ ; Where $A_n = A - k_n$ and $B_n = \frac{C}{A_n}$ ; ($B_n > A_n$ always).

I was able to convert the data in the post into a gradient by the following method:

$m_k = m_k + m_{k-1}$.

[Doesn't help me find $0=f(k_n)$ and $0=f(k_m)$].

Note that this is fine for data that can be stored into an array or list. I'll still need to find a method to generate some form of gradient in real-time. If I discover something or create an artificial gradient, I'll post it here.

[image]

Comment: If the function is not smooth but cheap to compute, you can try using non-gradient based optimization methods such as Genetic Algorithm or Particle Swarm Optimization.

Comment: Nothing in the graph indicates that there should be any better method than generating all the data. If there's more structure to the data than can be inferred from the plot, you should describe it.

Comment: Having your post downvoted can be frustrating. However, that's a given in a public internet forum like this. When we post question, we ask other members to help / provide solution **for free**, I doubt telling them to get a life is the way to go. Maybe try to **hire** and **pay** actual mathematicians / engineers to work for you? That way you can tell them how to interact and solve the problem however you wish

Comment: Understood, and deleted. Yes... I should take note "for free". But if I see something not clear or lacks research I at least contact them to elaborate before I judge.

Comment: @steveK been there, done that. I cannot control other people, so I control how I react and how I post. On the internet, don't take things too personally

Comment: I updated post with more accurate data. Maybe this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Through substitutions, we have

$$
f\left(k_{n}\right)
=
\frac{
\sqrt{C}
}{
2\left(A-k_{n}\right)
}
-1
$$

Solving for $f\left(k_{n}\right)=0$ yields

$$
k_{n}=
A-\frac{\sqrt{C}}{2}
$$

Something is missing in your post. Do you have the values of $A$ and $C$, or are these unknowns and you wish to estimate them from the data?

Comment: $C$ is known, $k_n$ is also known and treated as in iterator.  Each point in the graph is $f(k_n)$. It looks like your substitutions are off a bit.  $A$ is known. $A_n$ and $B_n$ are calculated. But I'm only giving you the basics. There's a bit more ugliness going on inside the function.

Comment: When I get time, I'll add the extra information. Let me see if the "back" substitutions can help as you point out.